# "Gaming the system" by using the same class name multiple times

Tags: html, css

I've seen people using this technique multiple times where I work.

Say I have an element:

```
<div class="new tile">I'm a new tile!</div>
```

I want to set the color of this tile as red, so I do so:

```
.tile { background-color: red; }
```

It works fine for a couple of months. But then someone else writes a new rule to set color below this one:

```
div.new { background-color: blue; }
```

The old rule had a specificity of 0 1 0 and this one has 0 1 1, so the color is changed.
His code is none of my business, but I don't like my tile set to blue, so I "force" it to red:

```
.tile.tile.tile.tile { background-color: red; }
```

This new rule has a higher specificity of 0 4 0, so it does set the color of the tile to red.

Is this intentional? It looks like a terrible practice - right up there with (mis)using `!important`, because this is basically referencing the same class. IMO, they could just patch this in some future CSS revision to only consider one class/element/id once per selector.

Fiddle if you want: https://jsfiddle.net/x634zh7u/

Edit: I see this question is closed as opinion based. What I mean is, does the CSS standard mention this anywhere as to why using the same class multiple times works?

Comment: What makes "this tile" special and requiring a red background? `new` might be acting as a signifier, but `tile` is fairly common. You'd be better off having a modifier on a class name that indicates the purpose of this tile to make it red - `new tile tile_highlight` or  similar.

Comment: If you share your CSS classes with someone who can write code which is "none of your business", make sure you use a prefix system or something of the likes to not clash your CSS class names. There's no good way around that if you are mixing CSS from different sources meaning different things for the same "semantic class"

Comment: It's a well known and fairly widely used practice. There's no danger of it ceasing to work in the future. But yes, artificially increasing the specificity is a red flag that you're not using specificity the way it was intended to work, and is likely to result in further specificity wars between your CSS rules.

Comment: You really want your tile to be red so you write `.tile.tile.tile.tile`, but your teammate really, really wants their "new" element to be blue, so they write `div.new.new.new.new.new.new`. What have you solved? The solution is for your team to collectively agree what colour a "new tile" should be. Then one of you writes `.new.tile {...}` and the issue is resolved.

Comment: @Zhaph-BenDuguid I know that, and I would, but the point here is that these clashes are causing people to implement rules which don't really address the base problem. As for my personal solution, it'd be something that makes it clear, like: `.tile .tile_red`.

Comment: @Jcl Or, use a module on the top and subsequent layers(which is what we've agreed upon in our team): `.myModule .myTile.tile.new`

Comment: @Alohci We just use LESS/Sass these days which encourages modularity and solves the specificity issue. However, it's still required to be careful in naming the hierarchy and individual elements so as to not confuse others.